# Job Search appears to be broken for searches like "C#"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

Over the past month or two, I've noticed a problem with the job search.

When I search for "C#" (without the quotes) and check "Allows Remote" under Location, I get a lot of results that do not include *C#*. A couple of month ago, this seemed to work correctly.

This also seems to affect the jobs that are emailed to me as part of an alert. (I.e., most jobs sent do not involve C#.)

Comment: I think Jon Skeet has taken all the C# Jobs...

Comment: Why is there no interest in this? Search has recently been broken in the past few months AFAIC.

Comment: @David Careers bugs usually get a response quickly, any reason this one is different?

Comment: @ShadowWizard was travelling over the weekend and couldn't push changes or update the post due to unexpected lack of wifi :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

We've recently been refactoring some things around job search and this slipped through the testing process. Elastic tends to ignore things containing symbols (such as C# and C++) in its default analysis; we've changed that so it respects these and many others.

I've just pushed a build to prod that fixes the issue. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Just checked it 2 mins ago, it made no difference to me. Although I noticed the lower case version works, 'c#', but not 'C#'

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa Good spot, thanks. Elastic char filters are case sensitive. Pushing to prod and re-building the index now. Should be available in five minutes or so.

Comment: The fix appears to be up now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, definitely noticing this. You used to get 3-5 PAGES of C# results in London.

Now, if you search for "C#" and place as **London**, you will be lucky to find **one** result regarding C#, and even that, is buried on page 2, or so. Leaving out location will generally find you C# roles though, so might have to do something with that extra filter(location / allows remote, etc)

Seems to me that search algorithm is broken.

Comment: Yes, and it appears to be broken from a change that was made fairly recently. But I've posted the issue here and, before that, reported it to a stackexchange support contact. I'm really surprised no one is responding to this.